# Failing to attach event listener to window object in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Can someone please why can I not attach an event listener to window object in nextjs? When I try 'resize' event, everything works fine, but with 'load' event it seems 'load' event is not recognized'

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("load", (e) => console.log(e));
  });

  return <div>Hello world</div>;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to attach a listener to the load event? Could you achieve what you need using the [useLayoutEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) hook instead?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the page has already loaded when this code begins to run. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but from what i see it can be done with just the useEffect hook.

You can verify what i just said by running this snippet :

```
const handler = (e) => console.log(e, "here");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
      handler();
    } else {
      window.addEventListener("load", handler);
      return () => document.removeEventListener("load", handler);
    }
  }, []);
```

Also I have to note that this is not nextJs specific, this is just react.

Comment: To be fair to esentai, there doesn't seem to be any guarantee of event/hook order, and from the way useEffect vs useLayoutEffect works I would actually expect the load event to *not* have fired when useEffect runs